# How to handle exceptions when programming with Java?

Tags: java, exception

I am studying Java these days, and I have realized that it is important to handle exceptions in my codes.

I just what to ask how to handle exceptions with various methods?

Is it to examine the method I use to see what exception the method has thrown? In the example below I have to see what exception method m() throws.

```
try {
    m();
} catch(SomeException e) {
    ...;
}
```

Is there any train of thought to handle exceptions when programming with Java?

Comment: **Depends**.... Your question is unanswerable.

Comment: thats not easy to answer. There are books dealing only with that issue :-)

Comment: read your book...put some effort

Comment: It's unlcear what you're asking about: the syntax of Exceptions, how they work, or how exceptions and exception handling code should be designed?

Answer (score 2):

The main skill to learn is how to *not catch* exceptions, but let them propagate up the call stack into the exception handler at the appropriate level.

Some rules of thumb:

- catch the exception early (close to where it appeared) only if you have an actual escape route, a different way to complete the request in progress;
- *either* log the exception *or* rethrow it, never both;
- the place high up in the call stack is called the *exception barrier*: this is the unique place where to log the exception as an error;
- don't be mislead by checked exceptions: most of the time the checked/unchecked distinction is not salient. *Rethrow* the checked exception (wrapped in a `RuntimeException`) when you have no code in mind to recover from it, which is the case most of the time. You could also declare the exception in your method header, but that is rarely practical;
- be very careful not to let an exception result in a resource leak: all the acquired resources must be released in the `finally` block.

Reading these lines you'll note that most issues around exceptions are not demonstrable on minimal, textbook examples. Exceptions are about the information and control flow in fat codebases.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need to log the exception, at least. And when 
catching the exception make sure your catch block is not empty.

Some of them you can handle, some you cannot (for them you 
usually need to fix your code as they indicate a bug in it).
So some are expected, others are programming errors.

Some are RuntimeExceptions (unchecked), others are not RuntimeExceptions 
(i.e. are checked). RuntimeExceptions you don't need to declare in methods 
or catch (i.e. you're not forced to do so by the language itself).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html

The subject is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to do a few [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) on exception handling, you could use:

```
        try {
            m();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

to see what exception is being thrown and then read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with samples like this as mentioned in below links that will give you clear clarification about the exception handling  Do it with practically bro...

```
The 'Throwable' class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language
Exceptions are broadly classified as 'checked exceptions' and 'unchecked exceptions'. All RuntimeExceptions and Errors are unchecked exceptions. Rest of the exceptions are called checked exceptions. Checked exceptions should be handled in the code to avoid compile time errors.
Exceptions can be handled by using 'try-catch' block. Try block contains the code which is under observation for exceptions. The catch block contains the remedy for the exception. If any exception occurs in the try block then the control jumps to catch block.
If a method doesn't handle the exception, then it is mandatory to specify the exception type in the method signature using 'throws' clause.
We can explicitly throw an exception using 'throw' clause.
```

http://java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-exception-handling-tutorial